# Collect log messages and print only when error has been logged

Tags: c#, logging, serilog

I'm using *Serilog* and would like to output Debug logs only when an exception occured/error has been logged.
For example It should log the Debug informations from the last 30 seconds to a file.

**Simple example:**

```
log.Debug("Don't log to file");
log.Error("Log Debug info now to file");
```

Does [Serilog](https://serilog.net/) support a feature like this?

Comment: I am not sure I got it right: you want debug log retroactively for the last 30 seconds counted from an error log?

Comment: Something like log4net's BufferingForwardingAppender. Sorry, I'm not aware of something equivalent in Serilog.

Comment: @KlausGütter Alright thanks for the suggestion on log4net. I will try it out and hope in the future we get something similiar for Serilog.

Comment: As Serilog is extensible, you might be able to implement something equivalent also for Serilog.